# Is it appropriate to ask about an open position by email before actually submitting a full CV?

Tags: applications, japan, europe

I am in a dilemma, as the title says. Currently I am at a PostDoc position in science at uni. I was planning to start looking for jobs in the industry  in six month from now.
Yesterday I found a pretty nice job offer in my region were I would fit right in. The deadline for the application is 01.09.2015 (very soon !). I would really like to apply for this but things are a bit complicated.
My projects where I am working now are not finished and I agreed with my boss that the earliest time for me to leave would be in six month from now. So by asking for a letter of recommendation I would imply that I am ready to leave sooner and possibly upset him and the rest of team. Also it is probably impossible to produce a full CV with recommendations and have it arrive by paper mail within the deadline.
Since this offer's deadline as almost due it might be futile to apply there anyway since they already have candidate.

Hence my question: Is it appropriate to send a short email inquiring about this position to avoid upsetting people and to gain some time on preparing a proper CV ?

I should add that I am actually happy at my position now, just this position fits really well, so I would risk upset people if I had a chance there. Also I am pretty specialized already, which makes really appropriate job offers in my region rare.

I am grateful for advice.

Comment: 01.07.2015 is past

Comment: my bad, should be 01.09.2015, fixed it

Comment: Are you sure they need a letter of recommendation? The "industry" works differently than "academia". While letters of recommendation are quite normal in the academia, the industry usually asks for professional references from your previous employer(s), and those are usually asked for *after* you clear the interview. However, I am unclear about industry hiring a candidate from academia.

Comment: @MaskedMan, that is valuable information. For the last things I applied I had to include two letters of recommendation with the application. But that was academia in Japan. What environment are you talking about. I guess Europe or US.

Comment: @Stefan_R: please add a broad location tag to your question because as MaskedMan rightly says letters of recommendation are not commonly requested or considered for industry positions in US/EU. As for your actual question: what is your goal in sending the mail? Checking if they're still accepting applications? That's usually what a deadline is for. It's conceivable that they have already closed applications if their candidate pool is large enough but they might not even respond if that's the case. Employers often don't respond to questions from candidates that they're not actively considering.

Comment: @Stefan_R I was referring to the Indian context, which I am most familiar with, because I work here. However, I have a fair deal of familiarity with US & EU, having worked with people from US & Germany for about 8 years. My general observation is, at least in context of this question, there is not much difference in hiring in "industry" of various countries, and likewise in "academia" of various countries. The difference is between "industry" and "academia", not so much between the countries.

Comment: @Lilienthal Exactly that. Just saw that offer and dont have a good CV/application ready. Asking if that job is still available. Maybe extend deadline. I dont mind negative or no answers though. I just dont want to appear rude when I might apply there in 6 month time even if there is no postion posted.

Comment: I once reported to a manager who joined the "industry" after working in "academia" for several years. Over several coffeetime- and lunchtime-conversations, I have learned about the practices in both worlds. When we hired guys from the academia (usually folks who had just completed their PhD - and perhaps continued to "work" at the University for a while after that), we asked for the recommendation letters, but when we hired guys from other companies, we would only ask for professional references *after* they had advanced to a sufficiently advanced stage in the interview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely appropriate.  If time really is of the essence, it won't hurt to call rather than email.

I've had both calls and emails from people who were interested in a job for which I was recruiting.  I'd much rather have someone clarify things *before* an interview.

All CVs nowadays are submitted either online or via email - so you shouldn't worry about the postal service.

Judging from your date format and use of the word "CV", I assume you're in the UK?  Generally speaking, industry references come *after* you accept the role.  So no need to worry about a reference letter just yet.

The bigger concern to me is that you want to leave in 6 months.  Depending on the job, up to 3 months is a common notice period.  It would be worth clarifying with the hiring manager whether that's an acceptable timeframe for them before formally applying.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, although it seems to come from anecdotal evidence. Still valid.
I am actually from Germany and the job in question is in the Netherlands. However, all materials and their website are English, so probably "international" rules apply.
For your concern about the time: I can leave my current position in 6 month and nobody can be upset. Projects should be finished be then or another person can  be hired and trained in that time.

Comment: What I meant was that I am willing to leave earlier for that job, although I would try to negotiate for that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it appropriate to send a short email inquiring about this position
>   to avoid upsetting people and to gain some time on preparing a proper
>   CV ?

**It's appropriate, but probably not very productive.**

You really can't say "save a place for me, since I don't have time to prepare my CV" and expect a positive response.

Instead, write your CV, and omit the letters of reference. If it's necessary in your field, include something like "references available on request". That will get the CV to the hiring company before their deadline, and start everything in motion.

That said, applying now for a job that you cannot start for 6 months is a bit unusual in "industry" (perhaps not so in academia). Be sure to broach that subject in your cover letter, so as to avoid wasting your time and the hiring company's time.

Comment: "You really can't say "save a place for me, since I don't have time to prepare my CV" and expect a positive response." Exactly that. Making a CV without reference letters as suggested might be the best thing to do. I will be honest with my preferred timing as to not waste mine and their time. Good advice.